# How to fix Error XAGJS7028 :Could not load assembly 'Xamarin.AndroidX.AppCompat.Resources in .NET MAUI?

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, xamarin.android, maui

I'm migrating my Xamarin forms code to .NET MAUI. After migration when I build my Android project I get the following error:

```
Error XAGJS7028 System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load assembly 'Xamarin.AndroidX.AppCompat.Resources,  Perhaps it doesn't exist in the Mono for Android profile?
```

I have no clue how to fix this. Any suggestions?

Comment: Did you update the nuget packages in your project to the versions supports .net?

Comment: @LiyunZhang-MSFT Yes I have updated all the Nuget packages.

Comment: Did you try to install the `Xamarin.AndroidX.AppCompat.Resources` nuget package for the android part?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know that when we migrated both of our application from Xamarin to Maui we deliberately removed all package references and brought in each one at a time, so we knew we only brought in what we needed. After doing that we no longer have the AppCompat in either of our projects.

Answer (score 1):

I've had a similar issue today and adding nuget package `Xamarin.AndroidX.AppCompat.Resources` (version 1.1.0.2) actually fixed the build for me.